# Convert python dictionary to python list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

```
dictionary = {0:0.2, 9:0.4}

pylist = [0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4]
```

Which is the efficient way to convert dictionary to pylist ? The keys in dictionary form the index in the list, and respective values in the dictionary become the values in list. The keys in the dictionary are going to range between 0 to 9, inclusive. the length of the list would be fixed i.e. 10.

```
pytuple = [ (0, 0.2), (9,0.4)]

pylist = [0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4]
```

Alternatively, Which is the efficient way to convert pytuple to pylist ? The first element in tuple form the index in the list, and respective second value in the tuple become the values in list. The keys in the dictionary are going to range between 0 to 9, inclusive. the length of the list would be fixed i.e. 10.

Comment: What governs the length of the resulting list?

Comment: Why is there a `0` at the end of the list? Before looking for an "efficient" method, do you have the problem properly scoped?

Comment: BTW, the `0.4` is in the wrong place in the list if I follow your pattern. I think you want index `0` to be `0.2` and index `9` to be `0.4`

Comment: I'm guessing you want something like this: `pylist = [dictionary.get(i, 0) for i in range(10)]`

Comment: Still makes no sense, why is the 0.4 not the last element....

Comment: Ok, I think this is a good illustration of why you should spend some time reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This was two lines of code that really wouldn't have been too difficult to get right before releasing the question into the wild. While we may be able to iteratively get to a solution, these downvotes will count against your account so please do take some time to read through those guides.

Comment: `pylist = [dictionary.get(i, 0) for i in range(max(list(dictionary.keys()))+1)]` will work as well if your dictionary keys exceed 10

Comment: @rahlf23 the size of list is fixed.

Comment: Just providing you a solution that will work outside of your extremely specific example.

Comment: @rahlf23 the last sentence of the problem clearly stated the list size is FIXED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some measurements for converting dictionary to pylist, here are the results:

```
from timeit import timeit    

dictionary = {0:0.2, 9:0.4}

def method1(d, n=10):
    return [d[i] if i in d.keys() else 0 for i in range(n)]


def method2(d, n=10):
    return [d.get(i, 0) for i in range(n)]


def method3(d, n=10):
    return [d.get(i, v) for i, v in enumerate([0] * n)]


def method4(d, n=10):
    l = [0] * n
    for v, k in dictionary.items():
        l[v] = k
    return l

print(timeit("method1(dictionary)", globals=globals(), number=1_000_000))
print(timeit("method2(dictionary)", globals=globals(), number=1_000_000))
print(timeit("method3(dictionary)", globals=globals(), number=1_000_000))
print(timeit("method4(dictionary)", globals=globals(), number=1_000_000))
```

Output is:

```
1.8713272300001336
1.8894721449996723
2.15010558800077
0.5128111490002993
```

It's clearly to see, that `method4` is fastest - firstly create the fixed list of zeros, and then iterate just keys that need to be changed.

Based on that fact, converting tuple to list should follow similar pattern: creating fixed list and then iterate over pytuple and change values in that list.

EDIT:

I did some test with random dictionaries as well:

```
# creating random dictionary
n = random.randint(1000, 100000)
idx = list(range(n))
dictionary = {}
for i in range(random.randint(100, n)):
    dictionary[random.choice(idx)] = random.random()

print('n =',n)
print('len(dictionary.keys() =', len(dictionary.keys()))

print(timeit(f"method1(dictionary, n={n})", globals=globals(), number=100))
print(timeit(f"method2(dictionary, n={n})", globals=globals(), number=100))
print(timeit(f"method3(dictionary, n={n})", globals=globals(), number=100))
print(timeit(f"method4(dictionary, n={n})", globals=globals(), number=100))
```

The results:

```
n = 82981
len(dictionary.keys() = 32083
1.203233296999315
1.1194271739987016
1.3668270919988572
0.2243523440010904
```

Comment: These results may be a little biased because you're using the same `dictionary` with only 2 entries- so any method that has to do 10 iterations will be slower than one that only has to iterate over only 2. A better test would be to create multiple test dicts with a random size (and random `n`).

Comment: @pault Did some testing with random dictionary as well. With this, the `method3()` is closer to first two methods, `method4` still leads.